# ButterKnife doesn't bind views after syncing gradle - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I have a problem with `ButterKnife` library. My views stopped binding after syncing gradle - before it was working without any problem.
I attached some code.

**build.gradle (app)**

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.navigation)
BottomNavigationView navigation;

private Fragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fragment = new GraphFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }

        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        return true;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}}
```

**ButterKnife logs**

> D/ButterKnife: Looking up binding for
>   com.example.azkb.instproject.refactor.MainActivity D/ButterKnife: Not
>   found. Trying superclass android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
>   D/ButterKnife: MISS: Reached framework class. Abandoning search.

Answer (score 4):

The problem occured when I added Kotlin to my project.

Solution:

kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'

Thanks for downvoting :)

Comment: Great! I have same issue for long time, and hours of researching didn't give me the answer that you give. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem that basically had the same solution. The issue for me was that the Annotation Processors of two different libraries were stepping on each other. In the end, getting them all to use the kapt solved the problem.

AnnotationProcessor is deprecated in the newer versions of AndroidStudio, so I suppose this is the way forward.